# Should I start trading Science for Money after unlocking the entire science tree in KSP?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Yesterday, after completing my Jool mission, I have gathered enough science to unlock all nodes of the science tree in the R&D department and I have over 1300 science left.

Should I use the administration building to start a plan that takes some of the science I gather and gives me money for it in exchange, seeing as I have no use for science anymore? Or is there anywhere else I can use these extra science points?

Comment: Are you playing with or without mods?

Comment: Playing Without mods

Answer (score 24):

Science points are only used to unlock nodes in the tech tree. Once you've unlocked all of them, you can freely sell all of your science for funds with no loss whatsoever.

Comment: I think I saw a statement somewhere on the net that you can upgrade some of your parts with science? I am on 1.3.1 so maybe it was available on previews versions?

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov Since1.2 there is support for part upgrade in game engine but it is not used by game as far as I know. Some part mods do use it a bit, and there is also [Kerbal Research & Development](https://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/index.php?/topic/128204-13-kerbal-research-development/&) mod.